# Playlistitems batch insert YouTube API v3

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm trying to create a playlist and add playlistitems using curl_multi in PHP. The reason i need to use a multi request is that the process seems to take ages to add (up to) 200 playlist items and hits a 30 second timeout on our platform (which i cannot change).

The multi curl request works fine, and is really quick, but the response that i get back from YouTube shows that playlistitems are overwriting eachother - the id parameter that YouTube generates is identical for multiple items and the position attribute is the same for different requests. Therefore from 200 requests i'm getting approximately 130 successful playlist items in my playlist.

To attempt a workaround i set the snippet.position when constructing the request but this does not work either as i suspect that i cannot add an item to a position that is not an increment on an existing playlistitem position.

I've been looking around for a solution to this and it appears to be a known problem

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-api-javascript-client/9Qdf0LCYSZs/MOcYxFKtWMQJ
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14310562/how-to-correctly-use-google-api-python-clients-batchhttprequest

What i would like to achieve would be either:

- An option in v3 (that i may have missed) to batch insert multiple playlistitems into a playlist. It seems to be possible to add multiple entries in v2 but not v3.
- A way to ensure my multi curl requests do not overwrite eachother
- Add Playlistitems as part of constructing a Playlist

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Please file a feature request as described below so it can be tied to an internal request

Answer (score 0):

It's a "known" problem of the API and it has already been filed as a defect in the past. However, it's no longer an open defect issue. But the problem has not been solved, but slightly improved by giving less failures. Maybe file it as an enhancement where you propose a possible better result. (For example, the API must  make 100% sure that all valid videoId's are actually present in the playlist by doing a "verify" with an internal retrieve. Which is faster then you can do, since you don't have to send extra requests.) Adding a delay between each request should result in having less failures.
You can file enhancements or defects here (after checking, if one is not already filed): 
https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/list?q=label:API-YouTube

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I grouped the videos in batches that contain a video from every playlist. So if you have 5 playlists, first batch will contain 5 videos the first one from each playlist and so on. It's not a great solution but it's better than no batching at all.

For ~1000 videos grouped in 40 playlists the insert operation was 6 times faster.
Also here is the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5408) filed for the Youtube API team.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're seeing is related to the playlist positions. Since the insert requests are async the following request overwrites the previous request.

I'm trying to resolve this by doing a waterfall of requests (waiting for the previous request to complete).

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, recursive function works please see a following answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39687078/4254357

based on that answer, I could add multiple videos(60 items) in a playlist at once by calling this function. it would worth try a recursive function.

```
    function AddSong(addingVideoIds, idx, addingPlaylist_id) {

        gapi.client.request({

            path: '/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet',
            method: 'POST',
            body:JSON.stringify({
                snippet: {
                    playlistId: addingPlaylist_id,
                    position: 0,
                    resourceId: {
                        videoId: addingVideoIds[idx],
                        kind: 'youtube#video'
                    }
                }
            })

        }).then(function(response) {

            jsonObj = response.result;

            $(".status").append("<span style='font-weight:bold;'>" + jsonObj.snippet.title + "</span><br/>");

            if (idx < addingVideoIds.length) {
                AddSong(addingVideoIds, ++idx, addingPlaylist_id);
            } else {
                $(".status").append("idx: " + idx);
            }

        }, function(reason) {
            $(".error").append("[" + addingVideoIds[i] + "]" + reason.statusText + "<br/>");
            if (idx < addingVideoIds.length) {
                AddSong(addingVideoIds, ++idx, addingPlaylist_id);
            } else {
                $(".status").append("idx: " + idx);
            }
        });

    }
```

https://github.com/konbuerimaki/text2playlist